# Ubuntu 18.04 login loop after upgrading from 16.04

Tags: upgrade, login

I just upgraded my system from 16.04 to 18.04. It's on an old ThinkPad W520. Now I'm stuck in a login loop. I get GNOME or Ubuntu GUI just briefly, then it kicks me back to the login screen. I know it's common, but I've tried what I can find including:

1. ownership of `.Xauthority` (it's user:user) some other ownership I can't remember
2. update graphics driver to recommended (Nvidia 390)
3. `startx` from terminal

and some other things I can't remember.

What should I do to fix the issue? Is there a log I can share to pinpoint the problem? (How can I even get the log from my PC and into this question?)

Output of `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-==========================================-===================================================-============-=====================================================================================================================================================
ic  caribou                                    0.4.21-5                                            amd64        Configurable on screen keyboard with scanning mode
ic  icedtea-netx-common                        1.8-0ubuntu8~18.04                                  all          NetX - implementation of the Java Network Launching Protocol (JNLP)
iF  irqbalance                                 1.3.0-0.1ubuntu0.18.04.1                            amd64        Daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems
ic  libc6-i386                                 2.27-3ubuntu1.2                                     amd64        GNU C Library: 32-bit shared libraries for AMD64
ic  libesd0:amd64                              0.2.41-11                                           amd64        Enlightened Sound Daemon - Shared libraries
ic  libhal-storage1                            0.5.14-8                                            amd64        Hardware Abstraction Layer - shared library for storage devices
ic  libhal1                                    0.5.14-8                                            amd64        Hardware Abstraction Layer - shared library
ic  libturbojpeg:amd64                         1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.4                              amd64        IJG JPEG compliant runtime library.
ic  libturbojpeg:i386                          1.5.2-0ubuntu5.18.04.4                              i386         IJG JPEG compliant runtime library.
ic  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:amd64                    0~git20131104-1.1                                   amd64        Texture compression library for Mesa
ic  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386                     0~git20131104-1.1                                   i386         Texture compression library for Mesa
ic  libunistring0:i386                         0.9.3-5.2ubuntu1                                    i386         Unicode string library for C
ic  linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic               4.4.0-79.100                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ic  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic         4.4.0-79.100                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ic  nvidia-304                                 304.135-0ubuntu0.16.04.3                            amd64        NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.135
ic  nvidia-common                              1:0.5.2.5                                           amd64        transitional package for ubuntu-drivers-common
ic  nvidia-current                             304.135-0ubuntu0.16.04.3                            amd64        Transitional package for nvidia-current
ic  virtualgl-libs:amd64                       2.3.3-1~preciseppa1                                 amd64        Library files for virtualgl
ic  virtualgl-libs:i386                        2.3.3-1~preciseppa1                                 i386         Library files for virtualgl
```

Comment: did you remove the previous  nvidiapackages?

Comment: while trying to reinstall some packages I'm also getting "Errors were encountered while processing:
 irqbalance" and attempts to reinstall this package result in no file name for irqbalance:amd64.  could this be related and how do I fix it?   I also tried going into lightdm but they didn't help

Comment: I don't know,  maybe,  I've purged all nvidia packages and reinstalled older nvidia drivers.  same thing.   so frustrating I'm going down rabit holes and am out of my league.   is there a log file that will just tell the problem?

Comment: could be related, something off wIth your apt or dpkg.  Please add to your question `lsb_release -a` and `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`

Comment: lab_release -a  showed no lab modules are available. distrtor id ubuntu description ubuntu 18.04.5 lots release 18.04 codename bionic

Comment: SORRY I oculdn't put this in a better format.  This was the piped output then I had to copy it in small blocks due to character limits here .

Comment: No worries - I've added the comment text to your question and formatted it as code. If you need to add more things to your question, you can just click the small grey "edit" link under it (sorry it's a bit hard to spot). If you do that, you should also see a small but helpful guide to Markdown formatting to the right of the editor, unless you're on a mobile device or something else is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | egrep '^ic' | awk '{print $2}')
```

This is an atempt to remove packages in unclean state

Then identify other nvidia-packages on your system with

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

and remove then.

Make a reboot.

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Show you which driver for your nvidiacard is the right one. Install it with apt or ubntu-drivers.